# Dates select from Mysql to work with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

i'm trying to hightlight all dates in datepicker from mysql but is not working, i think the problem is with array or i don;t know, the thing is when i write in user_busy_days variable ['2019-12-01','2019-12-02']; is working, but with the code below is not working. any help appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT dates FROM mls_cereri GROUP BY dates");
      $Data= Array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
         $Data[] = $row['dates'];
    }
        $event =   json_encode($Data);
      ?>
```

Javascript:

```
var user_busy_days =  '<?php echo $event; ?>'; // <- Working example:  ['2019-12-01','2019-12-02']

 $('#to_date').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true,
    format: "yy-mm-dd",
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,

    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                calender_date = date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var search_index = $.inArray(calender_date, user_busy_days);
                if (search_index > -1) {
                    return {classes: 'non-highlighted-cal-dates', tooltip: 'User available on this day.'};
                }else{
                    return {classes: 'highlighted-cal-dates', tooltip: 'User not available on this day.'};
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: it generates ["2019-12-20", "2019-12-21"] from PHP

Comment: Are you sure? Looks like it generates `'["2019-12-20", "2019-12-21"]'` - remove the `'` from around `'<?php echo $event; ?>'`.  Confirm with `console.log(user_busy_days.length)` - if it's 28 it's a string.

Comment: I have removed the ' and is working now.. thank you @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendered, this line:

```
 var user_busy_days = '<?php echo $event; ?>';
```

becomes

```
var user_busy_days = '["2019-12-01", "2019-12-02"]';
```

which is wrapped in a string, so the check `$.inArray(calender_date, user_busy_days);` is checking against the characters in the string rather than the strings in the array.

Remove the `'` so `user_busy_days` becomes an array:

```
 var user_busy_days = <?php echo $event; ?>;
```

---

Extra:

The code `(date.getMonth()+1)` will also need the 0+slice trick for months 1-9, assuming the php dates output as 2020-01-01 (example only shows 2 digit months)